# Update(Rename) values of a column based on the values of another column in same table - T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to rename a column based on another column in the same table. Example - I have a table as below

```
Row#    Name      Date            id
-------------------------------------
  1      aaa      2018-03-02      Null
  2      aaa      2018-03-02      123
  3      aaa      2018-03-02      456
  4      bbb      2019-07-05      Null
  5      bbb      2019-07-05      Null
  6      bbb      2019-07-05      345
```

Here, I would like to check if the name and sent date match - if both the condition match and the Id is NULL, no changes in the name but if the id is not NULL then I want to rename the 'Name' field as 'aaa (temp)' in the same table.
I'm not sure how to compare the id field and rename the table if its not NULL (irrespective of what the value is) below is the solution I'm expecting (Since the name & Date are same but the Ids in row 2 & 3 are not NULL)

```
Row#    Name          Date            id
-------------------------------------------
  1      aaa          2018-03-02      Null
  2      aaa(Temp)    2018-03-02      123
  3      aaa(Temp)    2018-03-02      456
  4      bbb          2019-07-05      Null
  5      bbb          2019-07-05      Null
  6      bbb(Temp)   2019-07-05       345
```

Comment: Match I mean 
```Select * from table1 as a 
Inner join table1 as b on a.Name = b.name and a.date = b.date ```

Comment: Semantics are very important for anything to do with programming. In this case, you are **NOT** renaming the column. You are updating the value of some records in the column. It's important to understand the difference.

Comment: using "Select * from table1 as a  Inner join table1 as b on a.Name = b.name and a.date = b.date" it won't be enough because you dont have a unique identifier for each row each row is going to match with itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can made a update with inner join

```
UPDATE e1 SET name = CONCAT(e1.name,' ( Temp )')
FROM #example e1
INNER JOIn #example e2
    ON e2.name = e1.name
    AND e2.date = e1.date
WHERE e1.id IS NOT NULL
```

But because you dont have a unique identifier for each row is going to also update the row that dont have a match, bc each rows is going to match with itself.

If you have uid is pretty easy

```
UPDATE e1 SET name = CONCAT(e1.name,' ( Temp )')
FROM #example e1
INNER JOIN #example e2
    ON e2.name = e1.name
    AND e2.date = e1.date
    AND e2.id_row <> e1.id_row
WHERE e1.id is not null
```

if you don't really have a unique identifier you can easily add it with this query

```
ALTER TABLE #example ADD id_row INT IDENTITY NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists` and `case`:

```
select t.*, 
       (case when id is not null and 
                  exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.name = t.name and t2.date = t.date and t2.id is null)
             then concat(name, '(Temp)')
             else name
        end) as new_name
from t;
```

If you want to update the value, then you can use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, 
             (case when id is not null and 
                        exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.name = t.name and t2.date = t.date and t2.id is null)
                   then concat(name, '(Temp)')
                   else name
              end) as new_name
      from t
     )
update toudpate
     set name = new_name
     where name <> new_name;
```

You can also phrase this as:

```
update t
    set name = concat(name, '(Temp)')
    where t.id is not null and
          exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.name = t.name and t2.date = t.date and t2.id is null);
```

Comment: I have a table with 500M records and I need to have them renamed based on this logic. I guess the update statement with exists will be having performance issues considering the volume of data.. any thoughts?

Comment: If you have an index on `(name, date, id)`, the performance might be better than you expect.